# Android studio projects not saved when it hangs

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, projects-and-solutions, android-ide

I am facing a weird experience with Android studio that during when it suddenly hangs, the previous changes that I made in my project are not saved. This issue happened for me several times when I close the Android studio manually from Task Manager during system crash or when I get Android studio not responding error. This kinda error is not occuring if I save the workspace often through `ctrl+s`(Save) or  `ctrl+shift+s` (Save All), but these issues I have never faced with Eclipse previously I used for development. So kindly please mentor me whether is there any settings that I have to change or update in my Android studio to resolve this issue. Your solution would help and useful for me to prevent my code from losing the changes I made. Thanks in advance.

Please text me if my question is not clear. Expecting your valuable answers and solutions. I have been facing this issue since I started using Android studio and because of this I have lost lots of data in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you allocated the correct amount of ram to the avd? As well as having enough to run studio anyway? Additionally Cpu can be an issue if you're using something like an i3 or low end i5. 
I can't run studio on my laptop due to it being generally bad but also the Cpu can't take the load.